# PHP/Zend: How to force browsers to don't show warnings on webpage for a particular case?

Tags: php, zend-framework, warnings, httprequest

I am trying to get twitter updates like this:

```
try {

  $doc = new DOMDocument();
  $doc->load('http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/1234567890.rss');
  $isOK = true;

} catch( Zend_Exception $e ) {
  $isOK = false;
}
```

If there is not problem with internet connection then $isOK = true; is set. But if there is a problem in loading twitter page then it shows following warnings and does not set $isOK = false;

**Warning: DOMDocument::load(http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/1234567890.rss) [domdocument.load]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found in /var/www/vcred/application/controllers/IndexController.php on line 120**

I don't want to see above warning on my webpage in any case. Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: Not ZF related at all, is it? You're using DOM, not Zend_Service_Twitter.

Comment: I am using DOM in controller/actions, therefore I thought that there may be a problem with zend try-catch.

Comment: try/catch is a nothing particular to ZF either. See http://de2.php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php. You get the Warnings because: *If an empty string is passed as the filename  or an empty file is named, a warning will be generated. This warning is not generated by libxml and cannot be handled using libxml's error handling functions. - http://de2.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.load.php*

Comment: OK. Anyway. Do you have any solution for this question without blocking all warning.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Several options:

[Suppress all errors for just this function call](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php)

```
@$doc->load('http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/1234567890.rss');
```

which is the same as

```
$oldLevel = error_reporting(0);
$doc->load('http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/1234567890.rss');
error_reporting($oldLevel);
```

Suppressing errors this way is generally frowned upon, as it makes code harder to debug. Like Shrapnel pointed out, you want to disable public display of all error messages on a production system anyway. On Dev systems you are encouraged to use [`error_reporting(-1);`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php), which would enable `E_ALL` and `E_STRICT`.

If you want to use [`try/catch`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php), you can also change default [error handling](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.errorfunc.php) and convert all errors to exceptions by doing

```
function myErrorHandler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline) {
    throw new Exception($errstr, $errno);
}
set_error_handler("myErrorHandler");
```

This is a global change though and affects everything raised. You'd also have to use `catch(Exception $e)` instead of `Zend_Exception` then in your code, but it would work. Note that the above would convert everything, even Notices, so you will also get an Exception about `$isOk` being undefined if you are trying to access this later. Feel free to adapt the handler to your liking and check out the [user comments for `set_error_handler` for more refined versions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php).

Another global change would be to change the application.ini in your application folder, e.g. letting Zend Framework control error handling:

```
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1
```

Change these to your needs. They are the same as in PHP.ini, e.g.

[display_errors](https://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors):

> This determines whether errors should be printed to the screen as part of the output or if they should be hidden from the user.

[display_startup_errors](https://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-startup-errors):

> Even when display_errors is on, errors that occur during PHP's startup sequence are not displayed. It's strongly recommended to keep display_startup_errors off, except for debugging.

Comment: @Gordon How can add your Answer to my favorities!? ;) Howewer… you forgot to write about `ini_set`, .htaccess and recompiling PHP with source code changes of default error reporting level ;)

Comment: @takeshin thanks. I don't think we can fav answers. Shrapnel already mentioned `ini_set` so I didn't. No use in repeating what others said unless it contains something new imho. Also, my answers generally do not intend to cover each and every possible solution. Leaves some room for other answers :)

Comment: Have considered changing your nickname to 'PHP Community Wiki'? ;) Anyway, thanks for all the answers, they are always a good reading.

Answer (score 2):

```
ini_set('display_errors',0);
```

it should be set this way on any production site.
users shouldn't be allowed to see system error messages at all

Comment: thanks its work for me.. Yes this code is working for avoid single page error or notice or warning but put this code into controller. :)